# Flutter Ripple Doesn't finish animation before route is pushed

Tags: flutter

Flutter version: Flutter 3.13.1 • channel stable

This is a pretty small nitpick but it has been bothering me and it has me wondering if I'm doing something wrong or if there is a bug within the framework. Or if this is actually intended UX.

When navigating to another route from any action that involves a ripple (i.e. clicking a material button) upon returning to the original screen the ripple then finishes its animation. In my opinion this gives a jarring experience when returning back to a screen since it looks buggy and as if there was a click you didn't make. See the below gif for clarification. When pressing back you can see the ripple finish.

[image]

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const OtherScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Foo'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've returned to Flutter after a year or so and do not remember this being an issue in the past. Indeed, my apps made around 2021 do not have this happening. I also do not see it present on [their documentation for navigation to a new screen](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Is there anyway to fix this that does not involve removing the ripple effect all together?

Note that this is happening for me on an emulator and on a real device in release mode.

Comment: You can try with GestureDetector:onPanEnd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this pageTransitionsTheme to my theme. Looks to be specific to using material3

```
theme: ThemeData(
    useMaterial3: true,
    colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
    pageTransitionsTheme: const PageTransitionsTheme(
      builders: <TargetPlatform, PageTransitionsBuilder>{
        TargetPlatform.android: ZoomPageTransitionsBuilder(
          allowEnterRouteSnapshotting: false,
        ),
      },
    ),
),
```

Comment: It resolves the issue. I found your solution on flutter github issue. For someone who want to know more, [see here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119897)

Answer (score 0):

The second route you are opening is drawn on the top of the first screen, creating this "bad" UX look.

There are several ways you can solve this.
You can **delay** the opening action, to make it only appear after the first animation ended.
For instance, if your first animation takes **2 seconds**, you need to Flutter the opening action by **2 seconds**. This can be achieved with a Timer and a Future.

```
// Delay something for 2 seconds
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {
  // Do something
});
```

Another option is that instead of opening a new **Scaffold**, you could only create a method that replaces the content inside your current **body**, and then the **appBar** apearence (title, and background color).
This can be achieved using the default build method.